# Как проверить, совпадает ли путь к файлу с regex?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как сделать универсальную проверку и для Windows и для macOS для данного пути?

(сейчас оно валидно только для macOS)

`/dist\/node\//.test(filePath)`

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна именно регулярка, попробуйте так:

```js
const re = /dist[\\/]node[\\/]/

console.log(re.test('dist\\node\\'));
console.log(re.test('dist/node/'));
```